# Perl code for string replacement

Tags: regex, string, perl

I want to replace in a string the substrings "[ids]", "[order]", and "[limit]" with three other substrings (passed as parameters to my routine).

But I want to cancel the special meaning of "[...]" if "[" or "]" is preceded by "\" ("\[", "\]"). Also "\" should cancel itself: "\\" means "\".

How to implement this in Perl?

Note that we may use something other instead of "[ids]", "[order]", and "[limit]". This is not set in stone.

Comment: The proper terminology: "I want `\ ` to escape `[`, `]` and itself."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use an existing templating [module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template) instead of inventing yet another one?

Anyway, here's a parser that will handle your format.

```
my %replace = (
   ids => ...,
   ...
);

my $out = '';
for ($in) {
   if (/\G    ( (?: [^\\\[\]]+ | \\. )+ )    /xsgc) {
       $out .= $1;
       redo;
   }

   if (/\G \[ ( (?: [^\\\[\]]+ | \\. )+ ) \] /xsgc) {
       die if !exists($replace{$1});
       $out .= $replace{$1};
       redo;
   }

   die if !/\G\Z/xsgc;
}
```

Comment: It can be done in a single s///, but it makes error checking harder. Or at least weirder. (When's the last time you saw `die` in a regex pattern?)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub replace_squared_terms {
  my ($str, $hash) = @_;
  my $new = "";
  for(;;) {
    return $new if $str eq "";
    if($str =~ /^([^\[\]\\\/]+)(.*)/s) {
      $new .= $1;
      $str = $2;
    } elsif($str =~ /^\[([^\/\[\]]+)\](.*)/s) {
      die "Wrong template" unless exists $hash->{$1};
      $new .= $hash->{$1};
      $str = $2;
    } elsif($str =~ /^\\(.)(.*)/s) {
      $new .= $1;
      $str = $2;
    } else {
      die "Wrong template";
    }
  }
}

my $str = "[a] [b] \\[ [a] \\\\";
print replace_squared_terms($str, {a=>"123", b=>"XYZ"}), "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it:

```
sub replace{
    my ($str, $ids, $order, $limit) = @_;
    $str =~ s/(?<!\\)((?:\\.)*) \[ (?: (ids) | (order) | limit ) \]/
              $1 . ($2? $ids: $3? $order: $limit)/gsex;
    return $str;
}
```

Example:

```
print replace <<'_STR_', '<1DZ>', '<0RD3RZ>', '<L1M1TZ>';
[ids][order][limit]
\[ids]\\[ids]\\\[ids]
_STR_
```

Output:

```
<1DZ><0RD3RZ><L1M1TZ>
\[ids]\\<1DZ>\\\[ids]
```